# SEO, Links and Partials not working together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, lightbox

I have this link:

```
<%=link_to 'Free Trial', '/sign_up?partial=1', :rel => "#signup", :class => "sign_up_button"%>
```

This loads an overlay using Jquery Tools. And it works well.

Which when its in the controller I use:

```
 def sign_up
   if params[:partial]
   render :partial => 'pages/sign_up'
   else
   redirect_to '/users/sign_up'
   end  
 end
```

This works well, as when I click the link it loads the partial without the layout so looks nice in the overlay. And when I go to www.mysite.com/sign_up I get the partial rendered in the layout which looks great.

However because I am defining the variable in the link Google for example is seeing it as

```
/sign_up?partial=1
```

So the link it is linking to loads without the layout and looks terrible!

Is there a way to inlude a variable in the link that is not defined by the actual link? For example if i could pass the class of the link I could have it render differently. I want a Google link to render with the partial and the links on my site to render without the partial in the lightbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get around this was to use the canonical link in header tag

This means google will always send links back to the page without the argument.